# DumpEndpoint not found in SpringBoot 2.2.6, any alternate?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

We are using DumpEndpoint form spring-boot actuator. Our current version is 1.3.3. We have to upgrade to the latest 2.2.6 version. We are not able to find the DumpEndpoint class in the new version. The below mentioned code in our class is called internally by the spring-boot, I don't know what is the use of it.

Is there any alternate to the below mentioned code in the new version ?

```
@Bean
public static DumpEndpoint dumpEndpoint(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
       return new DumpEndpoint() {
              @Override
              public List<ThreadInfo> invoke() {
                     List<ThreadInfo> response = super.invoke();
                     try {
                            logger.info("Thread Dump:\n" + objectMapper.writeValueAsString(response));
                     } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                     return response;
              }
       };
}
```

Comment: I believe `dump` endpoint is now called `threaddump` and should give you the same result.

Comment: I didn't find the invoke method there, so how to implement it ?